# How can i call php Require from SQL string

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

i am seeking help with the following

So im using PHP 7.1 and MSSQL 2017, and IIS

i have some tables that are to large to hard-code or create a text out of them to input in a SQL table , so i created a separate file with a query to display the table.

but when i try to add to "`<?php require'table1.php';?>`"

as a Text or string in another Table, and is set in the browser it gets comment out by the browser

Is there any way to execute the require with out being comment it out?

for now i have just create a link for the tables to open in a new tab, but i really what then to open inside the original document.

So file 1 is the main query where it displays the information.

File 2 runs another query for the Table, i would like to set the `<?php require'table1.php';?>` on the main query so it displayed File 2 contents in File 1, rather than opening a new tab.

Main table would be like this

Title - ID - Message

Something - RK1 - Something Important

Something 2 - RK2 - `<?php require'table1.php';?>`

Something 3 - RK3 - Something Kinda Importan

i apologize if its confusing, let me know.

Any help is appreciated, tyvm.

Comment: I'm not following this at all. What does this mean: `but when i try to add to "<?php require'table1.php';?>"

as a Text or string in another database,`? I don't understand how `requiring` another php script held in file `table1.php` can be set as *"Text or string in another database"*? I feel like the terms `table` `database` and other terms here all being confused for one another.

Comment: yes, lol. So The table in file one in one of the cells has the require "<?php require'table1.php';?>", the whole column is set as text, i hope this clears my dumbness. So when the SQL querys the table contents, the values in that cell get comment out.

Answer (score 0):

**It's never a good idea to store code in the database** because if you're database gets compromised whoever managed to get access to your DB will also have access to running php code on your server and can cause even more damage.

I think what you're trying to achieve could be done within your php files alone.

Why don't you just require `table1.php` file in your main file?

**Edit:**
In your main php file you can can create a part that your ajax script can communicate with that allows you to retrieve the necessary table contents like so:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['tableChange'])) {
  $tableToDisplay = $_POST['tableChange'];

  switch($tableToDisplay) {
      case 'A':
        $realTableName = 'TableA'; 
        $isValidTable = true; 
      break; 
      case 'B':
        $realTableName = 'TableB'; 
        $isValidTable = true; 
      break;
      default:
        $isValidTable = false; 
      break; 
  } 

  if($isValidTable)  {
      $tableContents = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$realTableName."`"));

      //Then you can retrieve what ever rows you want from the current table with the array you create with mysql_fetch_array
      $row1 = $tableContents['name_of_row1'];
      $row2 = $tableContents['name_of_row2'];

      echo 'row1: '.$row1.' row2: '.$row2;
   }
  }
?>
```

Then you can make an ajax POST request to the main php file -- that passes a piece of data named "tableChange" that holds a string representing the table's identifier. In this case it would have to be set to either "A" or "B" in order for it to be accepted.

Here's an example with jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'main.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: {tableChange: 'B'},
  dataType: 'html', 
  complete: function(dataReturned) {
     //Now print the contents of the dataReturned variable to the screen how ever you want
  }
});
```

Comment: All the information changes, using AJAX it changes the ID's to display different information with a click, you click option you get table A, Click option get table B and so and so forth, thats why the idea of a tableception is attractive to me, otherwise i would just set them as new tabs.

PS. The thing im trying to do is not meant for the public(if that helps)

Comment: I just updated my answer with an example of how you can accomplish loading your table's contents dynamically without storing code in the database. Let me know if you have any questions.